# Node.js Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream'

Tags: node.js

I get an error when I want to use gulp for deployment.

```
Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/pomelo/themes/pomelo/assets/js/node_modules/gulp-replace/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:50:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

So I use npm install readable-stream, but this is still the error.
Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to delete the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` folder, then run `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a core node lib. Try first,

```
npm cache clean
```

If not work, reinstall `node`

Comment: I reinstall node but also.